# bootstrap clodufiy3.4 on openstack mitaka error occured

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04, centos7, cloudify

Recently I installed cloudify 3.4 by following the cloudify's DOCS (I'm using Mirantis 9.0 as a cloud manager). while I was installing the manager by executing the following command-line :

```
cfy bootstrap --install-plugins -p openstack-manager-blueprint.yaml -i openstack-manager-blueprint-inputs.yaml
```

I faced an error which is

```
workflow failed : task failed 'nova_pluguin.server.creation_validation'->images
```

PS : I tested this command-line with different distributions of Linux : Centos 7 , ubuntu 12.04 and ubuntu 14.04 but I got the same problem.

your help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you please add more of the logs ?

Comment: This error message is not telling me why images for creation validation failed.

Answer (score 2):

Currently Cloudify Openstack plugin v1.4 official support is for Openstack Kilo.

See: http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.4.0/plugins/openstack/#compatibility
It is known to work on Liberty, apparently not on Mitaka.

Comment: There is some more information on using Cloudify with Mitaka here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloudify-users/U1xMdkZ0HqM